# paper-item - way to place value for paper-dropdown?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

Is there a way to place a value other than the text in paper item that is used inside a paper-dropdown? For instance, when form is submitted I would like `50` instead of `$50 dollars`. I tried placing `value='50'` but the form still used the text `$50 dollars`.

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="minimumPrice" name="minimumPrice">
      <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
        <paper-item>No min</paper-item>
        <paper-item>$50 dollars</paper-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be no official way to do that, but you could still technically accomplish your goal (with somewhat of a hack).

`<paper-dropdown-menu>` has an observer on its `selectedItem` that sets both its value and label to [the same value](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/27febe8/paper-dropdown-menu.html#L383-L384) (derived from the selected item); and the `selectedItem` is set by the `<paper-dropdown-menu>`'s [event listener on `iron-select`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/27febe8/paper-dropdown-menu.html#L345-L347), so you could add your own listener that overrides the label.

Here are the steps:

1. Specify the desired item value on each `<paper-item>`'s `label` attribute. Note the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` sets its value to the `label` of the selected item, but the text content of the `<paper-item>` still appears in the open dropdown menu (i.e., the listbox).

   ```
   <paper-item label="0">No min</paper-item>
   <paper-item label="50">$50 dollars</paper-item>
   ```
2. Add a listener for the `iron-select` event from `<paper-dropdown-menu>` in order to override the displayed label for the selected item.

   ```
   ready: function() {
     // <paper-dropdown-menu id="menu">
     this.$.menu.addEventListener('iron-select', (e) => {
       const paperItem = e.detail.item;
       this.$.menu._setSelectedItemLabel(paperItem.textContent.trim());
     });
   }
   ```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      const resp = e.detail.response;
      this.response = JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2);
    },

    ready: function() {
      this.$.menu.addEventListener('iron-select', (e) => {
        const paperItem = e.detail.item;
        this.$.menu._setSelectedItemLabel(paperItem.textContent.trim());
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.10.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-form id="myForm" on-iron-form-response="_onResponse">
        <form action="https://httpbin.org/get">

          <paper-dropdown-menu id="menu" label="Minimum Price" name="minimumPrice">
            <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
              <paper-item label="0">No min</paper-item>
              <paper-item label="50">$50 dollars</paper-item>
              <paper-item label="100">$100 dollars</paper-item>
              <paper-item label="200">$200 dollars</paper-item>
            </paper-listbox>
          </paper-dropdown-menu>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </iron-form>
      
      <pre>[[response]]</pre>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/kkjkkL?editors=1010)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<paper-item value="50" selected>$50 dollars</paper-item>`

This would select the $50 dollars as default and should grab the value

Answer (score 1):

You can add `label` property in `paper-item` to get the desired result.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="minimumPrice" name="minimumPrice">
  <paper-listbox id="test" slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
    <paper-item label="0">No min</paper-item>
    <paper-item label="50">$50 dollars</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

The `value` property in `paper-dropdown-menu` will always have the same value as of `selectedItemLabel` and the `selectedItemLabel` contains the value derived from the `"label"` of the currently selected item if set, or else the trimmed text content of the selected item.

**Update**

Another way:

Create a hidden `input` and assign the selected value to the hidden `input`'s value.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="minimumPrice" >
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="value">
    <paper-item value="0">No min</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="50">$50 dollars</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

<input is="iron-input" name="minimumPrice" id="hiddenSelected" type="hidden" value="[[selected]]">
```

And if you want first content to be selected by default you can assign inside `ready` function:

```
ready: function(){
    this.selected = 0;
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it will show the label value after selection. So, once a user selects $50 dollar from the dropdown, 50 will show in the element.

Comment: I have updated my answer posting alternative way using hidden input.